# Generalizing a proposition regarding orthonormal basis on $L_2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Currently I'm self studying functional analysis, namely Hilbert spaces. In the text, the author gives the following proposition:

> **Proposition A**: Let $\{\varphi_i(t)\}_1^{\infty}$ be a sequence of continuous functions that forms an orthonormal basis of $L_2[a,b]$. Then the system
> $$
> \left\{\varphi_{i}(t)\varphi_j(s)\right\}_{i,j=1}^{\infty}
> $$
> is an orthonormal basis of $L_2([a,b]^2)$.

After a careful read through, I now understand the proof. However, I thought possibly **Proposition A** could be generalized to the following:

> **Conjecture 1$^1$**: Let $\{\varphi_i(t)\}_1^{\infty}$ be a sequence of continuous functions that forms an orthonormal basis of $L_2[a,b]$. Then the system
> $$
> \left\{\varphi_{n_1}(t_1)\varphi_{n_2}(t_2)\varphi_{n_3}(t_3)\cdots\varphi_{n_m}(t_m)\right\}_{n_1,n_2,n_3,\dots,n_m=1}^{\infty}
> $$
> is an orthonormal basis of $L_2([a,b]^m)$.

Perhaps the question is *ill* defined. So, any thoughts here would be appreciated.

---

$^1$ Is this correct terminology, i.e. using conjecture...?

Comment: It seems like a reasonable conjecture . It might be easier to prove the more general conjecture: for $X\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ and $Y\subseteq \mathbb R^m$ and $\{\phi_n\}$ is a basis for $L^2(X)$ and $\{\rho_i\}$ is a basis for $L^2(Y)$ then $(x,y)\mapsto \phi_i(x)\rho_j(y)$ is a basis for $L^2(X\times Y).$ Your conjecture follows from this by induction. You might need to require $X,Y$ to be compact, and of non-zero measure.

Comment: (Or for any measure spaces $X,Y,$ in general perhaps even.) It might be worth asking for what pairs $X,Y$ is this true?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Thanks for the comments. I will have to look into this.